# Interfacing java and voip

Tags: java, voip

We have a small java application running on windows that needs to be able to make voip calls with text to speech sent to mobile and landline numbers and needs to send sms messages.

The application will notify contacts of specific alerts.

I have been searching and searching the past few days and I still do not even know where to begin.

I really just need a "push" in the right direction.

Any links or technologies that you could list off would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First solution is using Java API for Skype. You can fully operate it using java API: originate and answer calls, send SMS (if user has skype credit).

Other solution is to create calls using Asterisk and send SMS using one of available SMS libraries (e.g. SMSJ).